# SubMenu from Mobile in ASP.NET

Tags: mobile, menu, submenu

I created a site in ASP.NET with a 3 level Menu.
If I use it from a PC all works fine but if I use it from a Mobile device I can't access to the submenu items.
How can I do it?
Thanks.

Comment: give some details: libraries, some code

Comment: I reported the code below...

Answer (score 0):

**THIS IS THE HTML OF THE MASTER PAGE:**

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Defaultm.master.cs" Inherits="_Defaultm" %>

<%--<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
--%>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title>Call Center - Laservideo</title>   

    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    <style type="text/css">
        #form1
        {
            font-family: Calibri;
        }
        .styleCenter
        {
            text-align:center ;    
            font-family:Arial;
            font-size:14px;     
        }
         .styleCenter12
        {
            text-align:center ;
            font-size:12px;
        }

        .style1
        {
            width: 500px;
        }

      </style>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#000000" style="font-family: Broadway; margin-left: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;">

    <form id="form1" runat="server" 
    style="overflow: auto; font-family: Calibri;">
    <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="height: 100%">
      <tr>
        <td style="background-position: center top; background-image:url('Images/SfondoTop.jpg'); background-repeat: no-repeat;" 
          height="81" colspan="0" rowspan="0">
          &nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="background-position: center top; background-color: #FFFFFF; background-image: url('Images/SfondoCentro.jpg'); background-repeat: no-repeat;" 
          align="center" valign="top">
            <table style="width: 940px;" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
            <td valign="top" style="font-family:Arial; font-size:12;">
              <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" 
                style="font-family: arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 10px" width="100%">
                <tr>
                  <td>
                      <asp:Label ID="lblMasterTEst" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                  <td align="right">
                      &nbsp;</td>
                  <td align="right">
                    &nbsp;</td>
                        <td align="right">
                            &nbsp;</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td colspan="4" style="height:5">                          
                          <img alt="" height="1" src="Images/riga.jpg" width="100%" /></td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
            </td>
            </tr>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top" align="center">
                <asp:Menu RenderingMode="Table" ID="Menu1" runat="server" BackColor="#EDEDED" 
                  DynamicHorizontalOffset="2" Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="13px" 
                  ForeColor="Black" Orientation="Horizontal" StaticSubMenuIndent="10px" 
                  Width="600px" DynamicPopOutImageTextFormatString="" 
                  StaticEnableDefaultPopOutImage="False" StaticPopOutImageTextFormatString="" 
                  Font-Bold="True" Visible="False">
                  <StaticMenuStyle CssClass="styleCenter" />
                  <StaticSelectedStyle BackColor="#333333" ForeColor="White" 
                    CssClass="styleCenter" />
                  <StaticMenuItemStyle HorizontalPadding="5px" VerticalPadding="2px" 
                    CssClass="styleCenter" Width="156px" />
                  <DynamicHoverStyle BackColor="#333333" ForeColor="White" />
                  <DynamicMenuStyle BackColor="#EDEDED" CssClass="styleCenter" />
                  <DynamicSelectedStyle BackColor="#333333" CssClass="styleCenter" />
                  <DynamicMenuItemStyle HorizontalPadding="5px" VerticalPadding="2px" 
                    CssClass="styleCenter12" Width="156px" />
                  <StaticHoverStyle BackColor="#333333" ForeColor="White" 
                    CssClass="styleCenter" />
                  <Items>
                      <asp:MenuItem Selectable="False" Text="GESTIONE" Value="GESTIONE DATI" 
                        ToolTip="1">
                        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/ComunicazioniLettura.aspx" Text="Comunicazioni" 
                          Value="Comunicazioni" ToolTip="7"></asp:MenuItem>
                        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Account.aspx" 
                          Text="Account" Value="Account" ToolTip="1"></asp:MenuItem>
                          <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/UtentiAnagrafica.aspx" Text="Anagrafica Utenti" 
                          ToolTip="10" Value="Anagrafica Utenti"></asp:MenuItem>
                          <asp:MenuItem Selectable="False" Text="Mailing List" Value="Mailing List" 
                          ToolTip="8">
                              <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/MailingList_ELenco.aspx" Text="Elenco" 
                                  Value="Elenco" ToolTip="8"></asp:MenuItem>
                              <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/MailingList_Nuovo.aspx" Text="Nuova" Value="Nuova" 
                                ToolTip="8">
                              </asp:MenuItem>
                          </asp:MenuItem>
                          <asp:MenuItem Selectable="False" Text="Tablet" ToolTip="14" Value="Tablet">
                              <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/TabletAccessi.aspx" Text="Storico Accessi" 
                                  ToolTip="14" Value="Storico Accessi"></asp:MenuItem>
                              <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/TabletUpload.aspx" Text="Elenco File Caricati" 
                                  ToolTip="14" Value="Elenco File Caricati"></asp:MenuItem>
                          </asp:MenuItem>
                      </asp:MenuItem>
                      <asp:MenuItem Text="TABACCHERIE" Value="CLIENTI" Selectable="False" ToolTip="3">
                          <asp:MenuItem Text="Anagrafica" Value="Anagrafica Tabaccherie" 
                            NavigateUrl="~/AnagraficaTabaccherie.aspx" ToolTip="3"></asp:MenuItem>
                          <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/StatisticheChiamate.aspx" 
                            Text="Statistiche" Value="Statistiche" ToolTip="11"></asp:MenuItem>
                      </asp:MenuItem>
                      <asp:MenuItem Text="ASSISTENZA" Value="ASSISTENZA" ToolTip="2">
                        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/AnagraficaClienti.aspx" Text="Anagrafica Clienti" 
                          Value="Anagrafica Clienti" ToolTip="2"></asp:MenuItem>
                        <asp:MenuItem Text="Ticket" 
                          Value="Ticket" ToolTip="4">
                          <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Priorita.aspx?c=2" Text="Da valutare" 
                            Value="Ticket da valutare" ToolTip="4"></asp:MenuItem>
                          <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Priorita.aspx?c=0" Text="Da completare" 
                            Value="Ticket da completare" ToolTip="4"></asp:MenuItem>
                          <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Priorita.aspx?c=8" Text="Interventi tecnici da validare" 
                            Value="Interventi tecnici da validare" ToolTip="4"></asp:MenuItem>
                          <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Priorita.aspx?c=5" 
                            Text="Attesa intervento tecnico" ToolTip="4" Value="Attesa intervento tecnico">
                          </asp:MenuItem>
                          <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Priorita.aspx?c=10" Text="Interventi da fatturare" 
                            ToolTip="4" Value="Interventi da fatturare"></asp:MenuItem>
                          <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Priorita.aspx?c=9" 
                            Text="Invii materiale da validare" ToolTip="4" 
                            Value="Invii materiale da validare"></asp:MenuItem>
                          <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Priorita.aspx?c=6" Text="Invio materiale" 
                            Value="Invio materiale" ToolTip="4"></asp:MenuItem>
                          <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Priorita.aspx?c=7" Text="Invio preventivo" 
                            ToolTip="4" Value="Invio preventivo"></asp:MenuItem>
                          <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Priorita.aspx?c=3" Text="Sospesi" 
                            Value="Ticket sospesi" ToolTip="4"></asp:MenuItem>
                          <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Priorita.aspx?c=4" Text="Doppi" 
                            Value="Ticket doppi" ToolTip="4"></asp:MenuItem>
                        </asp:MenuItem>
                        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Ordini.aspx" Text="Ordini" Value="Ordini" 
                          ToolTip="5">
                        </asp:MenuItem>
                        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/StatisticheTicket.aspx" Text="Statistiche" 
                          Value="Statistiche" ToolTip="11"></asp:MenuItem>
                      </asp:MenuItem>
                      <asp:MenuItem Text="NUOVI CONTATTI" Value="NUOVI CONTATTI" 
                        NavigateUrl="~/NuoviContatti.aspx" ToolTip="9"></asp:MenuItem>
                      <asp:MenuItem Selectable="False" Text="TECNICI" Value="TECNICI" ToolTip="6">
                          <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/ElencoInterventi.aspx" Text="Interventi" 
                            ToolTip="6" Value="Interventi"></asp:MenuItem>
                      </asp:MenuItem>
                      <asp:MenuItem Selectable="False" Text="DISTRIBUTORI" Value="DISTRIBUTORI" 
                        ToolTip="4">
                          <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/FiltraDistributori.aspx" 
                              Text="Filtra Schede di Configurazione" 
                              Value="Filtra Schede di Configurazione" ToolTip="4">
                          </asp:MenuItem>
                          <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/PezziRicambioAnagrafica.aspx" 
                            Text="Pezzi di ricambio" ToolTip="7" Value="Pezzi di ricambio"></asp:MenuItem>
                          <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/ListinoMacchine.aspx" Text="Listino Macchine" 
                            ToolTip="13" Value="Listino Macchine"></asp:MenuItem>
                          <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/ClientiSchedaJamaica.aspx?c=AA00AA" 
                              Text="Configurazione JAMAICA STANDARD" 
                              Value="Configurazione JAMAICA STANDARD" ToolTip="N">
                          </asp:MenuItem>
                          <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/ClientiSchedaAggiungiOpzioni.aspx" 
                              Text="Schede - Aggiungi Opzioni" Value="Schede - Aggiungi Opzioni" 
                            ToolTip="N">
                          </asp:MenuItem>
                          <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/ClientiElenco.aspx" Text="Elenco Clienti" 
                            Value="Elenco" ToolTip="N"></asp:MenuItem>
                      </asp:MenuItem>
                  </Items>
                </asp:Menu>            
            </td>
        </tr>         
        <tr>
            <td valign="top" align="center">
                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder2" runat="server">
                </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top" align="center">
                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder3" runat="server">
                </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
            </td>
        </tr>    
        <tr>
            <td valign="top" align="center">
                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder4" runat="server">
                </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
            </td>
        </tr>   
        <tr>
            <td valign="top" align="center">
                &nbsp;</td>
        </tr>        
    </table>

          </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td height="144" 

          style="background-position: center bottom; background-image: url('Images/SfondoBottom.jpg'); background-repeat: no-repeat;">
          &nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
    </table>   
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```